# How can we apply static analysis tool for robot framework rflint to all of the repository?

Tags: robotframework, static-analysis, lint

I'm using the rflint static analysis tool in order to improve the quality of my robot scripts and review its code for UI testing.

I use current code to get an output in cmd related to a specific file:

```
rflint myTestSuite.robot
```

How can I apply it to the folder that contains all of my robot tests in just one click to get the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ask rflint to print out its online help with `rflint --help`, you'll see there is a command line option named `--recursive` (and the short version `-r`) which causes rflint to recursively process directories. Also, the very last paragraph in the help is this:

> If you give a directory as an argument, all files in the directory
>   with the suffix .txt, .robot or .tsv will be processed. With the 
>   --recursive option, subfolders within the directory will also be
>   processed.

Comment: It works, Great ! 
@Bryan, could you add the tag : `rflint` in stackoverflow?